Variability calculation based on standard deviation
I need assistance with calculating the standard deviation for a list of items, where the monthly consumption needs over the past 12 months are detailed for each item. My objective is to classify these items into three groups based on the volatility of their consumption:

Group 1: Items with highly fluctuating consumption.
Group 2: Items with moderately volatile consumption.
Group 3: Items with relatively stable consumption.

To achieve this classification, I intend to use a normalized standard deviation, calculated by dividing the standard deviation by the average consumption for each item. However, my current calculations of standard deviation do not seem to accurately reflect the consumption volatility. I would appreciate guidance on how to correctly calculate and normalize the standard deviation to achieve my goal.
$$
result = \frac{\sigma}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i}
$$
explanation for the calculation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GoYI746kEY
Example 1
For two items, I obtained identical values for the normalized standard deviation, calculated by dividing the standard deviation by the average consumption for each item. However, it is evident that item 2 is much more volatile than item 1.
Example 2
For item 1, a higher normalized standard deviation value is obtained, but it is clear that item 2 is more volatile than item 1.
Thanks!
